# ubuntu 14.04, restrict external IP access to phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I would like to restrict the external IP access to phpmyadmin but it does not work, even I changed the settings in /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf as followings.

```
# phpMyAdmin default Apache configuration
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 192.168.2.0/24
    Allow from 192.168.11.0/24
    Allow from 192.168.86.0/24
    ErrorDocument 403 ok
    RewriteEngine On
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
        php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
        php_flag track_vars On
        php_flag register_globals Off
        php_admin_flag allow_url_fopen Off
        php_value include_path .
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
        php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
# AuthName "phpMyAdmin Setup"
AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup
</IfModule>
Require valid-user
</Directory>
# Disallow web access to directories that don't need it
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from All
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from All
</Directory>
```

Comment: Frankly, it looks OK.  Q: `Deny from all`: should you capitalize `All`?  SUGGESTIONS: 1) Try `apachectl -t` and check for any errors.  2) "corrupt" your phpmyadmin.conf  with some "bogus text", and see if you get any errors.  If you don't get any errors ... maybe Apache isn't even reading your phpmyadmin.conf...

Comment: I have changed to All and the result is Syntax OK when I execute this command "apachectl -t"...and it works for internal IP restriction.....

Comment: Q: Are you saying a non-whitelisted internal addresses (e.g. 192.168.3.0) are successfully excluded, but that any/all external addresses (e.g. 10.0.0.1) can successfully access PHPAdmin?  Q: Have you looked at your Apache access.log to see the translated NAT address of some of these "external" addresses?

Comment: 192.168.2.0/24, 192.168.11.0/24 and 192.168.86.0/24 all are internal network and if I removed a subnet say 192.168.11.0/24 then the computer in this subnet unable to access to PHPMyAdmin.  so the phpmyadmin.conf is working fine for our internal but I don't want the other IP can access the PHPMyAdmin and the PHPMyAdmin.conf seems not working for external IP.

Comment: Thank you for your hints, the IP address from outside is via our firewall IP to access PHPMyAdmin, so the IP scope of 192.168.2.0/24 includes our firewall so that's why outside still able to access it no matter what I do...

Comment: OK: Glad you got it figured out :)